Battery charger monthly vs driving monthly
I know the best way to maintain batteries that are not used often is to connect it to a battery maintainer.
However if I can’t really find space to leave it connected at home I guess I’d have to go at of my way to either drive it once a month for the sole purpose of recharging or put it on a battery charger once a month.
I’ve heard that driving once a month for 40 minutes or so will recharge a battery and keep it going for a good few years.
If instead of driving monthly I just used a battery charger once a month would that also keep the battery good enough that it will last for a good few years similar to that of driving it once a month?
Thanks.

Yes, you can top up your battery once a month with a wall-powered charger and from a battery viewpoint, this is as good as driving the car (or in some cases, even better).
Caveats:

Be aware that while 40 minutes of driving may be enough, the typical car battery charger (2 to 5 amp) is way less powerful than the car alternator and may need to be left overnight for the same effect. Some chargers have "ready" indicator that will tell you how much time is enough, so the next time you will know better.

Be aware that some cars drain their battery more than others when left idle. Once in a month may be an extra hassle for most of the modern cars. I would start with once in 3 months.

Be also aware that the battery is not the only thing in a car that goes bad when not used. Moisture (=mold inside), corrosion on parts that get lubrication only when in motion, oil aging, etc, etc... so running the car at least once in 6 months is advisable.



If the car gets some direct sunlight every day, you may consider a small solar panel for topping the battery up. Works for me. The solar panel may be placed inside the car, under the windscreen.

I believe your last suggestion should be top of your leader board ... putting a small solar panel in your vehicle when not in use is an awesome way to maintain a battery when you cannot leave it connected to a power outlet.
